# How to move the latest file to SFTP server using WinSCP command

Tags: command-line, sftp, winscp

From the below location, I will have some files which will get modified some regular intervals. I want to move the last modified file to SFTP server.

I have used the below commands in WinSCP script.

```
option echo off
option batch on
option confirm off
open sftp:*************************
#change LOCAL directory
lcd "C:\SSISPCKG\JLRMENA\"
#copy an individual file
put -nopermissions -preservetime "C:\SSISPCKG\JLRMENA\eVHC_*.csv"
exit
```

How do I move the latest modified file from `C:\SSISPCKG\JLRMENA` directory?

I have tried with, but didn't helped out.

```
put -latest -nopermissions -preservetime "C:\SSISPCKG\JLRMENA\eVHC_*.csv"
```

Comment: What you have tried is correct. If it does not work, we need to see a log file (add `/log=c:\path\upload.log` to WinSCP command-line).